# java.lang.Character comparison in EL

Tags: jsf, character, el

I've a `java.lang.Character` bean property which I'd like to compare in EL as below:

```
#{q.isMultiple eq 'Y'}
```

It does not ever evaluate `true`.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: what problem is it your are experiencing? is there any error output?

Comment: "Its not working\" is not much of a description of the problem.  What's it not doing that it should?  What's it doing that it shouldn't?  Any errors?  Basically, what's different about what you expect vs what you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrary to "plain Java", whether you single or double-quote your literals in EL, they represent both `java.lang.String` instances. Your method is returning a `java.lang.Character` instance, so this will never return `true` in an `equals()` call between both instances.

The solution is to change it to a `String` or `boolean` return type. The property name `isMultiple` strongly suggests a `boolean`. You only need to remove that `is` from the property name and keep it in the getter method.

```
private boolean multiple;

public boolean isMultiple() {
    return multiple;
}
```

```
#{q.multiple}
```

An alternative is using an `enum`. This would only be applicable if you have more than two states (or perhaps three, a `Boolean` also includes `null`).

Answer (score 2):

Can also do this by converting the `Character` to `String` by printing it as body of `<c:set>` as below:

```
<c:set var="isMultipleVal">#{q.isMultiple}</c:set>
```

And then comparing it instead:

```
#{isMultipleVal eq 'Y'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using EL 2.2, one workaround is:

```
#{q.isMultiple.toString() eq 'Y'}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may need to look the property `isMultiple` in the Class of variable 'q'. Please verify your class having a getter method with signature as `public char getIsMultiple(){}`.

Also, are you sure `${q.isMultiple eq 'Y'}` gives `true`?